# How to use the general purpose button on environmental sensor board with the dev board

Tags: google-coral

I have the environmental sensor board connected to dev board. How can I let the system to callback a method or application when the general purpose button is pressed?
Thanks!

Comment: One way is to connect the button via the GPIO pins and then make use of the python periphery https://pypi.org/project/python-periphery/. how are you trying to connect the button ?

Comment: @Manoj Thanks!
I connect the environmental board to the coral dev board from 40pins GPIO. So tried with python-periphery library, but I can't figure out how to make it work with the button or the LED.
I tried following, but the LED doesn't turn ON. I couldn't try button since I don't know the pin number for the button.
gpio_140 = GPIO(140, "out")
gpio_140.write(bool(True)

From the coral dev board, I see two GPIO pins with direction, but both are "out". How can I find out the pin for the button and LED on environmental board?

Thanks!

Comment: Please walk through https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/gpio/#header-pinout in detail and you will get all these answers.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks! I got the button working now.

Answer (score 0):

Please walk through [this link](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/gpio/#header-pinout) in detail and you will get all these answers.

Table 1 from the above link shows the header pinout, including the device or sysfs file for each pin, plus the character device numbers. For a pinout that includes the SoC pin names see the Dev Board datasheet instead. You can also see the header pinout from the command line by typing pinout on the Dev Board.

Note: All I/O pins have a 90k pull-down resistor inside the iMX8M SoC that is used by default during bootup, except for the I2C pins, which instead have a pull-up to 3.3 V on the SoM.
Caution: Do not connect a device that draws more than ~82 mA of power or you will brownout the system.

Python periphery code will look like:

```
from periphery import GPIO

led = GPIO("/dev/gpiochip2", 13, "out")  # pin 37
button = GPIO("/dev/gpiochip4", 13, "in")  # pin 36

try:
  while True:
    led.write(button.read())
finally:
  led.write(False)
  led.close()
  button.close()
```